# What is the syntax to sequence statements in Gremlin?

Tags: groovy, titan, gremlin, tinkerpop

Within the Gremlin language (a Groovy child) I'm a little confused by the behavior and uses of `;`, `&&`.

For example, in GremlinClient REPL (running Titan 1.0 here) I might desire to add a few nodes at once:

```
gremlin> graph = TitanFactory.open("../conf/gremlin-server/titan-cassandra-server.properties")
==>standardtitangraph[cassandra:[localhost]]
gremlin> g = graph.traversal(standard())
==>graphtraversalsource[standardtitangraph[cassandra:[localhost]], standard]
gremlin> g.V().count()
==>0
gremlin> g.addV(label, 'Subject', 'ident', '1') ; g.addV(label, 'Subject', 'ident', '2')
==>v[4304]
gremlin> g.V().count()
==>1
```

OK, so `;` didn't work.  How about `&&`?  It doesn't quite have the semantics I want but I could work through it:

```
gremlin> g.V().count()
==>0
gremlin> g.addV(label, 'Subject', 'ident', '1') && g.addV(label, 'Subject', 'ident', '2')
==>true
gremlin> g.V().count()
==>2
```

Well... that's sort of ok.  Now I also need to be able to bind variables as part  of the sequence of commands.  Oddly, semicolon works here:

```
gremlin> g.V().count()
==>0
gremlin> g.E().count()
==>0
gremlin> g.addV(label, 'Subject', 'ident', '1') && g.addV(label, 'Subject', 'ident', '2')
==>true
gremlin> node3 = graph.addVertex(label, 'Subject', 'ident', '3') ; g.V().has('ident', '1').next().addEdge('dc:isPartOf', node3) ; node3.addEdge('dc:isPartOf', g.V().has('ident','2').next())
==>e[35z-6d4-2l91-9n4][8248-dc:isPartOf->12496]
gremlin> g.V().count()
==>3
gremlin> g.E().count()
==>2
```

Now here's the trick. How can I perform both these operations in one line (one Websocket request, in practice)?  I can't seem to even duplicate the above `node3 = ...` line via `;` and get proper functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you're talking specifically about [Gremlin language variants](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.2.1-SNAPSHOT/tutorials/gremlin-language-variants/), Gremlin is pure Groovy since Gremlin is a DSL and not a language per se. Technically, any valid Groovy is valid Gremlin.

Regarding the examples your provided, I believe you need to iterate your traversal via `.iterate()` (`.next()` would work since you're only adding one element).

```
g.addV(label, 'Subject', 'ident', '1').iterate() ; g.addV(label, 'Subject', 'ident', '2')
```

The Gremlin console automatically iterates the last Traversals only, so an explicit `.iterate()` for that second statement is not required. This is strictly equivalent to:

```
g.addV(label, 'Subject', 'ident', '1').iterate() ; g.addV(label, 'Subject', 'ident', '2').iterate()
```

If you want to execute multiple operations via WebSocket, you can just send multiline scripts. The following should work:

```
node3 = graph.addVertex(label, 'Subject', 'ident', '3')
g.V().has('ident', '1').next().addEdge('dc:isPartOf', node3)
node3.addEdge('dc:isPartOf', g.V().has('ident','2').next())
```

Note that with a more recent version of TinkerPop (I recall v3.1+), you can chain `.addV()` steps and add multiple vertices within the same traversal.

```
g.addV(label, 'Subject', 'ident', '1').addV(label, 'Subject', 'ident', '2')
```

This is not yet available in Titan since the latest stable release (v1.0.0) uses TinkerPop v3.0.1.

Comment: "Iterate your traversal" catches people every time. Also see: http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/tutorials/the-gremlin-console/#result-iteration - note that Gremlin was a "groovy" in TinkerPop 2.x. I would not really place that restriction on it anymore for TinkerPop 3.x.

Comment: Thank you so much!